# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException with set number of elements

Tags: java, indexoutofboundsexception

I am trying to simulate a terminal/file system. Right now I am working on parsing and tokenizing the commands.

I am trying to determine what is considered a valid command. My strategy is to check if index 2 element in my input array is anything other than the string "empty". If it is, my `checkValidCommand` method will return false.

I am currently getting this error when I run the program and enter in input as `"hi"`:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2
    at fileSystem2.MainActivity.checkValidCommand(MainActivity.java:43)
    at fileSystem2.MainActivity.main(MainActivity.java:66)
```

I believe this problem is caused by having my `String[] input` having only 3 elements.

code:

check valid input.

```
    private static boolean checkValidCommand(String[] commandTokens) {
        //boolean valid = false;
        if (commandTokens[0].equals("exit")) {
            return true;
        }
        else if (!commandTokens[2].equals("empty")) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Code that parses commands

```
String[] input = new String[3];

        for (int i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
            input[i] = "empty";
        }

        while(!input[0].equals("exit")) {
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            input = sc.nextLine().split(" ");
            if (checkValidCommand(input)) {
                System.out.print("Invalid Command!");
                continue;
            }
            System.out.println(input.length);
            switch(input[0]) {
                // vi
                case "vi":
                    System.out.println("hi");
                    break;
                // ls
                case "ls":
                    break;
                // mkdir
                case "mkdir":
                    break;
                // pwd  
                case "pwd":
                    break;
            }   
        }
```

Comment: What are you providing as input?

Comment: A string. For example "Hi"

Comment: And what would then be the result of `input = sc.nextLine().split(" ");`? Your splitting the `String` value `"Hi"` by the space character. How many elements will the created array contain?

Comment: Can you highlight the 43rd line from your **MainActivity.java** file for us here?

Comment: Change `else if (!commandTokens[2].equals("empty")) {` to `else if (commandTokens.length() > 1 && !commandTokens[2].equals("empty")) {`

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis 1

Comment: So you can't access the element at index 2, because there is none.

Comment: Or even `if (checkValidCommand(input))` can be changed to `if (input.length() > 2 && checkValidCommand(input))` to fix your problem.

Comment: I created `String[] input = new String[3]` and set them all to `"empty"` so I assumed that there was always going to be 3 elements in `input`. But as explained below is was marked to be garbage collected and a new `String[]` is created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command

```
input = sc.nextLine().split(" ");
```

does **not** fill the existing array (referenced by `input`) with data.

It creates a **new** array and assigns a reference to it to `input`.

Whatever `input` was pointing to becomes dereferenced and a subject to garbage collection.

Comment: I see. However I am now quite confused on how to initialize input in the first place. As you said, using `split` will dereference the previous `input` and create a new array for the new `input`. However, how can I initialize `input` in order to use the test case in the `while loop`?

Comment: You can not and actually do not need to. Just check the array length.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how to get the length of the array in Java (I will assume that it is `array.length()` for this answer so forgive me if I got it wrong) but basically you're accessing the 2nd element without ensuring that `sc.nextLine().split(" ");` will actually return 3 elements for you...

So I would recommend changing:

```
if (checkValidCommand(input)) {
```

To

```
if (input.length() > 2 && checkValidCommand(input)) {
```